# str_getcsv enclosures not working with newlines

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to process a CSV file containing newlines within a description field. However when using str_getcsv to split the rows into an array, it's spliting on the newlines within the enclosure as well.
Example:

```
$data ='header1,header2
value1,"value2a
values2b"';
$data = str_getcsv($data, PHP_EOL, '"');
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'header1,header2',
    1 => 'value1,"value2a',
    2 => 'value2b"',
)
```

Expected value:

```
array (
    0 => 'header1,header2',
    1 => 'value1,"value2a 
value2b"',
)
```

PHP version is 5.6.19 (cli)

Comment: I don't see any expected delimiter for your output.In your str_getcsv you gave delimiter PHP_EOL which means it will explode at new line..If you pass "," in place of PHP_EOL then also you can't the expected output

Comment: Is there another way to split on newlines that aren't enclosed in quotes? Or do you think I'll have to use some regex to do it?

Answer (score -1):

There are answers to my question here in the "User contributed notes" section: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Apparently PHP's CSV function don't follow the standards that are used by other CSV programs.